# How long pet animals or birds mourn?

Tags: death, animals, sadhana

It feels immense pain to lose a pet bird and due to this its pair bird is screaming and behaving so weird, silent sometimes and arrogant toward us. How long this will continue? Is there a chanting mantra to keep it calm and also relaxed?